# IntegrityError at /update/70 NOT NULL constraint failed: tohome_task.title

Tags: python, django, database

I was updating the data in the database by takin the data from an html form when this appeared. I have faced this problem earlier also but I dont remember how to solve it .

my views.py part

```
def update(request,pk):
task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
context = {
    'task':task, 
}
if request.method=="POST":
    task.title= request.POST.get('taskname' )
    task.save()
    return redirect('/main')

return render(request,"update.html",context)
```

models.py file :

```
class Task(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length =200)
complete = models.BooleanField(default = False , blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my html file :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-3">
    <form method= "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1 class="text-center">{{task}}</h1>
    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded " id="task_name" name="task_name"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Add the task !">
    <p class="lead text-center" > Do you really want to update ?</p>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type ="submit" >Update &raquo;</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html `input` element's `name` attribute does not match the key you are attempting to access in `request.POST`. You would need to update your `name` attribute on your `input` to `name="taskname"` as opposed to `name="task_name"`

I would also suggest taking a look at Django's [form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) and possibly adding validation since your error was caused by attempting to update the `Task.title` field with a `None` value